# Walking immediately after the meal

Tags: digestion

I find different views for this topic.

**First view,**

It is not a good idea to walk immediately after a meal as your stomach requires energy to digest the food and so you should not be using your energy on something else immediately after having food, which can affect digestion negatively. Should wait for sometime and then can walk.

**Second view,**

Walk immediately after the meal helps burning calories and even helps digestion and other benefits as well.

What is actually true?

Answer (score 3):

There is a belief that walking just after a meal causes fatigue, stomach ache, and other types of discomfort.But researches have found that walking just after a meal is more effective for weight loss than waiting one hour after eating before walking.It can help

- to prevent a lot of stomach problems, including indigestion and heartburn.
- lower your blood sugar,
- bring down triglycerides,
- Decrease cardiovascular risk by preventing high fluctuation of blood sugar just after meal.As blood sugar typically rises and then falls after eating, but large spikes and variations can raise cardiovascular risk..
- speed up digestion(increase metabolism)
- lower post-meal blood sugar levels in people with Type 2 diabetes
- help  burn calories and
- aid in weight loss.

  > It is quite clear that walking suppresses the glucose increase after a meal. Because glucose increases to its maximum at 30–60 minutes after a meal, walking must be started before the glucose level reaches a maximum, because once insulin is secreted it will play a role as an obesity hormone. It can be assumed that starting walking as soon as possible seems to be optimal to control blood sugar levels.
  >   [Source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3119587/)

References

http://www.healthyfoodhouse.com/the-6-benefits-of-walking-right-after-a-meal/

https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-power-rest/201307/when-walk-try-after-meals

http://livehealthy.chron.com/going-walk-immediately-after-dinner-lose-weight-10111.html

http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/06/24/really-the-claim-taking-a-walk-after-a-meal-aids-digestion/?_r=0

Comment: So which of those 4 blogs mention the research?

Comment: @jiggunjer Exactly! And CCR there are blogs like this as well which confuses me http://goqii.com/blog/should-we-brisk-walk-before-the-meal-or-after/

Comment: @jiggunjer http://livehealthy.chron.com/going-walk-immediately-after-dinner-lose-weight-10111.html this blog  has mentioned the researches and their findings ..also please click on " Source " highlighted in Answer which provides the link of a research and i have quoted its conclusion in the answer..

Comment: @PawanNogariya ...Friend, internet is full of answers of many doubtful things.. some are posting hoax and some are really authentic.. it would be rational if you consult the blogs which have good references and should accept the answer that most of the blogs are implying...